# WSO2 CEP thrift ip address not bound to eth0/sitelocal ip address of linux machine

Tags: linux, ip, wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi

1. Standalone mode

   - When I start WSO2 CEP server on my linux machine, the ip address which is displayed in the logs as below

Mgt Console URL  : https://<172.16.55.1>:9443/carbon/

- When I run netstat on that port, as below

linux-0rla:/test/home/CEP/data # netstat -tulpn | grep 9443

tcp        0      0 :::9443                 :::*                    LISTEN      28882/java

- ifconfig on machine shows

enp0s25   Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 64:31:50:42:93:17
          inet addr:10.201.1.171  Bcast:10.201.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0

vmnet8    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:50:56:C0:00:08
          inet addr:172.16.55.1  Bcast:172.16.55.255  Mask:255.255.255.0

The ip which my machine has exposed is 10.201.1.171, so ideally CEP server should have started on this ip only. Although it is accessible from eth0 ip as well from another machine.

2. HA mode

Now when I setup similar 2 machines for HA setup, this time the thrift ip also had similar issue.

- When I start WSO2 CEP server on my linux machine, the ip address which is displayed in the logs as below

Thrift Server started at 172.16.55.1 
Thrift SSL port : 7711
Thrift port : 7611

- When I run netstat on that port, as below

linux-0rla:/test/home/CEP/data # netstat -tulpn | grep 7611

tcp        0      0 172.16.55.1:7611        :::*                    LISTEN      28882/java

But here these 2 machines are not able to communicate with each other over thrift port for inter node transfer of events.

When I created HA setup on same machine in different folders, now it was working fine.

Is there a way to tell WSO2 CEP to start thrift and server on particular ip address ???

Answer (score 1):

The problem of CEP server getting started at vmnet8 address is due to VMWare running in your machine. You can check that with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vmware status
```

If  VMWare is running, you can stop that with:

```
sudo /etc/init.d/vmware stop
```

An then start the CEP again. Now the server will start on your machine's ip.

Comment: I tried removing the vmware interface but then my machine has other interfaces like eth0, eth1, eth2, eth3... so on. 

I noticed it somehow starts on last ip in list shown in IFCONFIG.

Anyways CEP server ip is not much of a problem, apart from only creating a bit of confusion.
Because CEP management console opens from browser on eth0 sitelocal ip as well.

Actual issue happens with thrift server because it gets hard bound to some random ip as shown in netstat output.